# Weblogic 10 application name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am currently working on a weblogic 10 application server that has several installed ears. I got a request to change the application name of some aps as they appear in

> Home >Summary of Deployments

I went to the appropiate Plan.xml and changed the  with the appropriate name, restarted the domain but the name did not change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple in the end. I added inside the EAR's manifest file the following entry

```
Weblogic-Application-Version: x.y.z
```

In this way I didn't have to mess up with any of the Weblogics configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by modifying `config.xml` file in

```
DOMAIN_NAME/config
```

You can just modify the name and restart the server.

```
 <app-deployment>
    <name>jms-rename</name>
    <target>DefaultServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\JMSTest\application\jms\target\jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
```

Comment: Well I didnt want to mess up with the cofiguration of WL. If I did that then I will be forced to do it in all WL that exists in the cluster and the different enviroments.